# Split up angular.json configuration into multiple files

Tags: angular

**Status quo:**
I'm working on a project, which has different sub projects, which are assigned to different teams. So my angular.json looks something like this:

```
{
  ....
  "projects": {
    "project-1": { ... }
    "project-2": { ... }
  ....
```

Is there a way to move the configuration for project-1 into it's own file.

**Reason:**
This would allow us to make the approval process better, where we can define CODEOWNERS per file, but not per file part. Since angular.json is over all projects, it needs the most approvals, which usually just ends up with the responsible team asking us to approve the change, because they changed the configuration responsible for them.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, this is not supported in Angular directly.

There is a build framework called Nx that does support this kind of destructuring. Instead of `angular.json`, you can create a `workspace.json` that supports an extended syntax:

> `angular.json`
>
> > Your `angular.json` file can be renamed to `workspace.json` and Nx will process it in the same way. The `workspace.json` has one additional top level property `version`. Setting `version` to 1 means the `workspace.json` file syntax is identical to `angular.json` When the `version` of `workspace.json` is set to 2, `targets`, `generators` and `executor` properties are used instead of the version 1 properties `architect`, `schematics` and `builder`.
>
> `project.json`
>
> > In version 2 workspaces, project configurations can also be independent files, referenced by `angular.json`. For instance, an `angular.json` may contain projects configured as below.
> >
> > ```
> > json { "projects": { "mylib": "libs/mylib" } }
> > ```

Reference: https://nx.dev/l/a/core-concepts/configuration